# Mixpanel track onclick img id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tracking, mixpanel

I am using mixpanel to track various events on website, I am unable to track onclick event on img_id. My php code of website looks like

```
 <div id="chunk-4">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img id="take_action_button_1" onclick="take_action()" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/action/invite.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img id="take_action_button_2" onclick="take_action()" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/action/give.png" />
```

I want to track how many user click on button1,2 and similarly i have 2 more button. Mixpanel code I tried is using tack links and with out. Here is what I tried

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
mixpanel.track_links("#take_action_button_1", "Track action button", {
    referrer: document.referrer
});
```

I also tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#joinus_form_button").click(function() {
// This sends us an event every time a user clicks the button
mixpanel.track("Submit form results page on clic"); 
});
</script>
```

I Am also having trouble with tracking my social media icon

```
<a class="item tweetbox  twicon" href="#"><img src="" /></a>
<a class="item google" target="_blank" href="link"><img src="" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This must work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#take_action_button_1").click(function() {
mixpanel.track("Submit button 1"); 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#take_action_button_2").click(function() {
mixpanel.track("Submit button 2"); 
});
</script>
```

Regarding social button: need to use code similarly.

If this code not working maybe you have problem in other place. Example problem with  connect to mixpanel ( you do not have js code for mixpanel on this page)

Comment: I tried that before and it was not working and js code is already on that page as other events are working and I made sure it's there. any suggestion?